# Pass data from model to view in GoLang

Tags: mongodb, model-view-controller, go

I am supposed to pass a list of objects which are stored in a MongoDB database from the back-end to the view, where I need to display the content of all the objects as a list (like a table) on an HTML page ? How should I do this given the number of table rows can be dynamic ?

Comment: I guess this would depend on what you mean by view, are you using some framework that has a view type? If yes it would help if you mention that in your question. Or are you talking in purely abstract terms? Then in pure Go, you would load those objects from mongo into a [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) and then use the [html/template package](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) to render the contents of that slice however you want... But really you should show what you've tried so far, show some code, or else you might have a difficult time getting help on SO.

Comment: By view, I mean an HTML page. @mkopriva

Comment: In that case I think you can use the already mentioned [html/template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) for what you trying to do.

Comment: But I need to display the result in a form of table with non-fixed number of table rows since my database can have any number of entries, how to do that ? @mkopriva

Comment: Basically, I need to print a list from my database on the HTML page, how to do that ? @mkopriva

Comment: You would use `range` to loop over your data inside the template and render it on the page. See example here: https://play.golang.org/p/kTQi9ouV15. Read the [text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) documentation for how to program your templates. Note that package text/template is not the same as package html/template but the interface for programming the templates is the same.

Comment: Can you please give an example/github project since I'm new to GoLang ? @mkopriva I have the HTML page in my `static/pages` folder and GO source code in `model/show_list.go` file.

Comment: Hi @Jarvis, sorry for the late reply, this [jimmykuu/gopher](https://github.com/jimmykuu/gopher) is one project that uses templates without resorting to some unnecessary framework, it also uses mongodb for storage. It's a chinese website, so the comments are in chinese which i can't read, but the code is very much readable and not overly complex. As an example take a look at the [book templates](https://github.com/jimmykuu/gopher/tree/master/templates/book) and the [book handlers](https://github.com/jimmykuu/gopher/blob/master/book.go) that render those templates...

Comment: ... and also take a look at how the `renderTemplate` method is implemented here: https://github.com/jimmykuu/gopher/blob/master/handler.go#L42. And the book model is defined here: https://github.com/jimmykuu/gopher/blob/master/models.go#L530-L542. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva will do.